# Remove margins in Mpdf v7

Tags: php, mpdf

How do I remove the margin set at 4 sides of the page in Mpdf v7?

I've already tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf( [ 'utf-8', 'A4', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] );
```

I've also tried this but I encountered a division by zero error:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf( [
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'format' => 'A4',
    'margin_left' => 0,
    'margin_right' => 0,
    'margin_top' => 0,
    'margin_bottom' => 0,
    'margin_header' => 0,
    'margin_footer' => 0
] );
```

Comment: There's not enough information to reproduce the issue. What you're doing is correct (just tested your second block of code just to be sure, I get no errors). The division by zero error is likely being caused by whatever you're putting into your pdf. Could you show us more of your code?

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla I get the division by zero when I change one of the margins to zero. margin 0.001 works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is correct.

If you are experiencing a division by zero error, try updating to a higher, preferably the latest version (v8.0.2) which works without errors.

Comment: I tried v8 but still I have the same problem. I used 0.001 instead of 0 and now it's ok.

Comment: what is the "same problem"? If you are experiencing any error, update your code example here to reproduce the error, as the simple constructor works fine. Also see Ismael Padilla's comment to the question.

Comment: "same problem"="division by zero"